# Determine token value by comparing with token replaced string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a tokenised string like so;

```
var route = a/b/{firstId}/c/d/{nextId}
```

and I am wondering if it is possible with regex to get the value of "firstId" via a second string with tokens already replaced.

Example, if I have a given string;

```
var partPath = a/b/33
```

I can do something like;

```
function getValueFromPath(path, route){
    //regex stuff
    return tokenValue; //Expected result 33
}

getValueFromPath(partPath, route);
```

Thank you,

C.

Comment: I think your route with desired `33` value does not match original route template. If values after {firstId} are not mandatory, that should be shown somehow. In general, I think the good idea would be to store original route as a regex itself, and then match input route against it.

Comment: How will you write part path if you wish to get nextId?

Comment: @closure, the idea is for it to be flexible, so that I can get values from part paths like; a/b/33, c/d/44, a/b/55/c/d/66

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo, that sounds like a good idea, are you able to give me an example, i'm not great with regex. Thank you

Comment: @claracruz: Small nitty-gritty but extremely important. In your example, c/d/44 should be /c/d/44. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

A regex solution would be overly complicated (if you didn't define the `route` with a regexp right away). I'd just use

```
function getValueFromPath(path, route){
    var actualParts = path.split("/"),
        expectedParts = route.split("/"),
        result = {};
    for (var i=0; i<expectedParts.length; i++) {
        if (i >= actualParts.length)
            return result;
        var actual = actualParts[i],
            expected = expectedParts[i];
        if (/^\{.+\}$/.test(expected))
            result[ expected.slice(1, -1) ] = actual;
        else if (actual != expected)
            // non-matching literals found, abort
            return result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
> getValueFromPath("a/b/33", "a/b/{firstId}/c/d/{nextId}")
{firstId: "33"}
> getValueFromPath("a/b/33/c/d/42/x", "a/b/{firstId}/c/d/{nextId}")
{firstId: "33", nextId: "42"}
```

---

Here's the same thing with "regex stuff" (notice that regex special characters in the route are not escaped, you have to take care about that yourself):

```
function getValueFromPath(path, route){
    var keys = [];
    route = "^"+route.split("/").reduceRight(function(m, part) {
        return part + "(?:/" + m + ")?"; // make right parts optional
    }).replace(/\{([^\/{}]+)\}/g, function(m, k) {
        keys.push(k); // for every "variable"
        return "([^/]+)"; // create a capturing group
    });
    var regex = new RegExp(route); // build an ugly regex:
    // regex == /^a(?:\/b(?:\/([^/]+)(?:\/c(?:\/d(?:\/([^/]+))?)?)?)?)?/
    var m = path.match(regex),
        result = {};
    for (var i=0; m && i<keys.length; i++)
        result[keys[i]] = m[i+1];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: hmm... that actually works, but I'm afraid it has to be a regex solution

Comment: @claracruz: Why? There's no reason to use regex, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a regexp like this:

```
function getValueFromPath(path, route){
    tokenValue = path.match(route)[1];
    return tokenValue; //Expected result 33
}

var route = /\/a\/b\/([^\/]+)(\/c\/d\/([^\/]+))?/;
var partPath = '/a/b/33';
getValueFromPath(partPath, route); // == 33
```

http://jsfiddle.net/firstclown/YYvvn/2/

This will let you extract the first value at the first match with `[1]` and you can get the nextId by changing that to `[3]` (since `[2]` will give you the whole path after the 33).

Comment: That would throw an exception if the route doesn't `match`!

Comment: @Joseph, This one wouldn't quite do the trick, because a/b/... will not always be those values, those values could be anything and the lists of path/route values will also vary.